# $ sign where did it originate?

Tags: signage

This sign is a very interesting one. I do not know where it originated in.
And why do we use it? How does $ sign relate to dollar?

Does it mean money? Sometimes I've seen it with double lines striking through it.

Comment: It is an interesting question but wikipedia has it covered http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dollar_sign

Comment: The Wikipedia response is very tentative. If the question can be "definitely and permanently answered by a single link," I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Wikipedia, the leading hypothesis is that the "U" & the "S" were written overtop of each other, and eventually the two bars of the "U" were collapsed into one.